# How to move a front image without affect the back image in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
function generate() {
    var c1 = document.getElementById('shadeDiv');
    c1.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);
    
    function mouseUp() {
        window.removeEventListener('mousemove', move, true);
        c1.style.top = "8px";
        c1.style.left = "565px";
    }
    
    function mouseDown(e) {
        window.addEventListener('mousemove', move, true);
    }
    
    function move(e) {
        c1.style.top = e.clientY + 'px';
        c1.style.left = e.clientX + 'px';
    }
    }
```

```css
 body {
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #ffffcc;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    #shadeDiv {
        border:1px solid;
        position:absolute;
        left: 565px;
        top: 8px;
        width: 145px;
        height: 227px; 
    }
    
    #shade {
        width: 145px;
        height: 227px; 
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Masking</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload="generate()">
    
        <div id="divImage">
            <img src="dotcard0.png" id="shade">
        </div>
    
        <div id="shadeDiv">
            <img src="shade.png" id="shade">
        </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Hi, these are the codes. If I select the "shade" image to move same time back image will select and popup. But I want if I select the "shade" image to move it will select only "shade" image and I need to move only vertically. But for now I can only move wherever in the page, but I want to move only vertically. So, summary is I want to only select the "shade" image without affect the "dotcard0" image and I need to move the "shade" image only vertically. Please help me.

> Thanks & Regards, Zajjith

Comment: All client side code?  No server code?

Comment: Yes. All codes are client side codes.

Comment: After pressed run code snippet please change to full page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can alter your code to be like this

```js
function generate() {
  var c1 = document.getElementById('shadeDiv');
  c1.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);
  window.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);
  var origY = null;

  function mouseUp() {
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', move, true);
    origY = e.clientY;
  }

  function mouseDown(e) {
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', move, true);
  }

  function move(e) {
    c1.style.top = (origY + e.clientY) + "px";
  }
}
```

Comment: If I click the front image back image will popup. How can I fix that?

https://ibb.co/vP0F1Mn

Comment: sorry I do not understand your question